# Python 3: Recursivley find if number is even

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x

I am writing a program that must find if a number is even or not. It needs to follow this template. I can get it to find if a number is even or not recursively

Comment: Have you tried _anything_ yet?

Comment: This template can't be right. Are you sure the first line isn't `def isEven(number):`? (You need the colon for it to work, and you need a parameter for it to be called with a parameter.)

Comment: @tzaman: Sure, he tried asking other people to do his homework for him. :)

Comment: @abarnert, this is not homework, this is a problem I found and am trying to solve for my own knowledge. However, troll as you wish.

Comment: @tzaman, I have tried but have failed to figure out a way to return anything into the main function call.

Comment: also @abarnet, you were right about the first line, i just edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This template will help. You need to fill in the commented lines. The one you have in the question won't work - you aren't passing anything into `isEven`. This will only work if `n >= 0`, otherwise it will crash your program. Easy enough to fix if you ever need to deal with negative numbers.

```
def isEven(n):
    if n == 0:
        # Number is even
    elif n == 1:
        # Number is odd
    else:
        # Call the function again, but with a different n
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. Seems the key was to return a boolean value

Answer (score 4):

The key is that you need to return a boolean value:

```
def isEven(num):
    if (num <= 0):
        return (num == 0)
    return isEven(num-2)
```

For larger numbers though this quickly exceeds the default maximum recursion depth for Python.  That can be remedied by calling `sys.setrecursionlimit(n)` where `n` is the number of recursive calls you want to allow.  `n` in turn is limited by the platform you are on.

Comment: Where does `num` come from? Your function doesn't accept any arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it works for integer values with `0 <= n <= sys.getrecursionlimit()-2`:

```
def even(n):
    return True if n == 0 else odd(n - 1)

def odd(n):
    return False if n == 0 else even(n - 1)
```

It's a nice example of a pair of mutually recursive functions. Not the most efficient way to find the answer, of course - but nevertheless interesting from an academic point of view.

Comment: I don't think the OP is too worried about efficiency, or he wouldn't be writing `isEven` recursively… And it is a neat example.

Comment: @abarnert I think that, too. Thanks!

Comment: An indirect and roundabout way to solve the problem, which doesn't fit well with the template/interface given by the teacher.  Fanciness for the sake of fanciness.

Comment: @wim My answer is correct, and I believe it's a _plus_ the fact that it shows a different way to solve the problem. Stack Overflow is about finding creative, correct solutions to problems, even if they don't fit a rigid template. The OP can simply ignore my answer, but other people might find it interesting. Please reconsider your downvote.

Comment: Well, it's still not 100% right—try `even(sys.getrecursionlimit()+1)`, which is an integer value `n >= 0`… But honestly, I don't think you need to explain the preconditions here at all. If the OP understands the code, they're obvious, and if he doesn't, they're not relevant to the problem.

Comment: OK I'll remove my downvote, because the question is insane in the first place.  probably the only 'different' way to solve the problem worth mentioning is introducing `operator.mod`

Answer (score 0):

A really dumb use case for recursion, but here is my version anyway

```
import random

def isEven(num):
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        # let's learn about recursion!
        return isEven(num)
    else:
        # let's be sane!
        return num % 2 == 0
```

*disclaimer:* if you submitted this you'd probably tick off the teacher and come across as a smartypants.

Comment: Not that I've taught anyone in a decade or two, but I think I'd give the student the option of "you get an F, or I waive the requirements so you can be bumped up to the intermediate class". :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking up wim's challenge to find a "different" way to do this: The prototypical recursive pattern is `foo(cdr(x))`, with a base case for the empty `list`… so let's write it around that:

```
def isEven(num):
  def isEvenLength(l):
    if not l:
      return True
    return not isEvenLength(l[1:])
  return isEvenLength(range(num))
```